# Finding a condition that maximizes the conditional correlation between two random variables

Tags: correlation, optimization

Let’s say I have $n$ independent and identically distributed samples that is, $(X_1,Y_1)$, $(X_2,Y_2)$, ... $(X_n,Y_n)$ which is my dataset.  I want to find a condition on $X$ such that the conditional correlation coefficient (say Pearson's correlation) is maximized. Formally, I want to find a function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \{0,1\}$  such that $corr(X,Y|f(X)=1)$ is maximized, where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, and $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

One thing possible is to assume a parametrized form for $f$, say a simple linear model or possibly a neural network, then somehow obtain an expression for the correlation using the samples in terms of the parameters of $f$ and then optimize for those parameters using something like gradient descent. The problem is how do I obtain the parametric expression for the conditional correlation?
Is there a simpler way to approach this problem?